# Collection View not scrolling?

Tags: ios, swift, swift2, uicollectionview

I'm not really sure what I'm doing wrong. I have a collection view that I populate dynamically. The user types in a movie title, I query omdb and parse the resulting json into cells. The problem is that the view doesn't allow me to scroll to view the cells off screen. Here's a screen shot:
[image]

Here's the a storyboard snippet:
[image]

**EDIT 1:**

[image]

Constraints:

Comment: Did you check if "User Interaction" is unchecked?

Comment: what are the constraints given to collection view.?

Comment: @SumanAdhikari "User Interaction" is checked. Each cell leads to another view that shows details for the movie selected

Comment: @HarshalBhavsar Edited question to show picture of constraints

Comment: Try to set bottom to view instead  of bottom  layout guide

Comment: Have you set the width and height for the CollectionView?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try this

```
int numberOfRows = self.dataArray.count / 2;
self.collectionView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(self.view.frame.size.width, (numberOfRows * heightOfCell));
```

Where dataArray is list of items.